# Implementation/translation of the $s^1_1$

Tags: computability

This is the Lisp code (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smn_theorem)) that implements the $s^1_1$ form of the $s^m_n$ theorem

```
(defun s11 (f x)
   (let ((y (gensym)))
     (list 'lambda (list y) (list f x y))))
```

since I don't know Lisp, can someone explain me what this code does and/or translate this code into other languages

Comment: Other languages = {Ocaml, F#, Java, Python, C}

Comment: Or a pseudo-code easily understandable by someone who knows these languages

Comment: I know this question seems code related and someone will say post it to stackoverflow, but the goal of the question is to understand better the $s^m_n$ theorem and probably will be useful also to other people who are studying complexity theory and don't know Lisp

Comment: If you don't know Lisp, how do you expect to understand Lisp code?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus in fact I asked to translate the code into another language. On wikipedia there's only in lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, `s11` a program which takes as its first argument a representation of a 2-arguments program e.g. a string like

```
def foo(x,y):
   return g(x,y)
```

and a number `n` as its second argument.

The result of `s11` is the representation of another program, obtained by "hard-coding" the value `n` for `x` in the source code, effectively removing the argument `x`. In the example above we would get the string

```
def newFoo(y):
   return g(n,y)
```

or something equivalent to that, e.g.

```
def newFoo(y):
   return foo(n,x)
def foo(x,y):  # original code unaffected
   return g(x,y)
```

The code posted by the OP does this using LISP lambdas. The part

```
(let ((y (gensym)))
```

generates a new variable name `y`, while

```
(list 'lambda (list y) (list f x y))))
```

returns the representation of the function

$$
\lambda y.\ f (x, y)
$$

where `x` is the value to "hard-code" (the one which we called `n` above).

The representation is a LISP s-expression / tree instead of a string, but the concept is the same. LISP is famous for being able to express code as data (roughly as an AST), and being able to run it in a simple way (homoiconicity).